# How change the value of variable after reading it from Firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change the value of the variable after reading it from the Firebase on button click. For example, if the value is 0 in firebase after button click it should change to 1 and if it's 1 it should change to 2. Also, it should reset to 0 after 4.

```
 on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                EditText editText =  findViewById(R.id.input);
                final String link = editText.getText().toString();
                fled1 = new Firebase("https://iot-5z6h8.firebaseio.com/");

                // Read from the database
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            state = dataSnapshot.child("Touch").getValue().toString();
                            value = Integer.parseInt(state);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + state);
                            value+=1;
                            if(value==4){value=0;}
                            Firebase fled1Child = fled1.child("Touch");  fled1Child.setValue(value);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {error.toException());
                    }
                });
```

I expect the value in firebase to change only on button click. But the value is changing in a continuous loop to 0-1-2-3-0-1-2-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is adding a listener that gets invoked every time the data at the given location changes.  And it's adding another new listener every time the button is clicked.  So, every time the button is clicked, you're going to multiply the amount of output you see.

If you want to [read data a single time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once), rather than adding a listener that listens all the time (until it's removed), use [addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)).